# I respawned in a strange place. How do I get back?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was playing Minecraft Pocket Edition Creative. My house was AWESOME. To add to it I decided to build a basement underground. One problem... I dug too deep so I died. But when I respawned it wasn't a snowy winter wonderland. I was on a sandy island. So, what happened?

Comment: Did you originally spawn in a snowy biome when you created the world?
Is there a chance you may have somehow reset your spawn?

Comment: Did you ever sleep in a bed? If so did that bed get destroyed somewhere between when you last slept and when you died?

Comment: This is why I enable extra chest option.  But i dont recall having that feature in PE, could be wrong.

Comment: If you want to make it easier to find your house, next time when you go to find a perfect spot, mark your way there from your spawnpoint with torches.

Answer (score 2):

If you did not sleep in a bed, set your spawnpoint using cheats, or if you destroyed your bed before falling out of the world, then your spawn will not be set and if you die, you will spawn where you originally spawned.

Comment: So you will need to retrace steps you made while looking for that snowy winter wonderland.